# how to give NIS users default ubuntu (desktop user) group permissions

Tags: ubuntu, redhat, nfs, nis

My central file server is running `Redhat` and I've configured this system to export shares via `NFS` and I manage user accounts with `NIS`. I've setup a couple of `Ubuntu` clients and realized, that the `NIS` users are not part of any of the standard `Ubuntu` groups. A local user usually belongs to the following groups:

```
$ groups
user adm cdrom dip plugdev lpadmin sambashare
```

My NIS users however only belong to the following groups:

```
$ groups
user
```

I could obviously add each `NIS` user to all the standard `Ubuntu` groups on each Ubuntu client that I'm using, but that requires me keep all systems up to date.

I was therefore thinking of adding the `NIS` users on the NIS server to the appropriate groups. Unfortunately, the group names and ids don't match between `Redhat` and `Ubuntu`. So
while the `plugdev` group on a Ubuntu system maps to group ID `46` the same group might have the ID `47` on my `Redhat` server.

**Therefore my question:** How do I match / map user groups in the most efficient way? ideally, each new NIS user will automatically be in the correct ubuntu groups. (Not having the right group permissions results in not being able to smbmount, etc, ...)

**EDIT** Ideally I would add each `NIS` user to a special `NIS` group and that would be translated on the Ubuntu clients to the groups `adm cdrom dip plugdev lpadmin sambashare`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a partial solution seems to be:

```
 $ sudo vi /etc/pam.d/common-auth

 # add line
 auth optional pam_group.so
```

Set group permissions for all authenticated users (not NIS specific)

```
 $ sudo vi /etc/security/group.conf

 # add line
 "*;*;*;Al0000-2400; audio,video,cdrom,plugdev,fuse"
```

any better solutions?

Comment: A note: obviously, this has to be done for all Ubuntu clients